# Intercept in fixed effects regression with feols

Tags: r, regression, stata, fixest

How do I get the intercept from a fixed effects regression using `fixest::feols`?

```r
library(fixest)
feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, iris)

#>             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
#> Sepal.Width 0.803561   0.071397 11.2548 0.0078023 **
```

For comparison, `reghdfe` in Stata does show the intercept (`_cons`):

```r
ssc install reghdfe
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/iris, clear
reghdfe seplen sepwid , ab(iris) cl(iris)

#>              |               Robust
#>       seplen |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
#> -------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
#>       sepwid |   .8035609   .0713974    11.25   0.008     .4963625    1.110759
#>        _cons |    3.38658   .2182857    15.51   0.004     2.447372    4.325788
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intercept can be calculated as the average of the sum of the fixed effects:

```r
est = feols(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, iris)
mean(est$sumFE)
#> [1] 3.38658
```

Comment: is it possible to recover the SE of the intercept as well?